# gulp-concat returns empty for two streams

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I'm building two gulp streams to squash my templates for two areas of the system, then I'm using `gulp-merge` and `gulp-concat` to merge them into one file.

What is strange is that switching the order of two streams, makes the `concat()` return an empty steam (and hence no final file).

To make it even more strange, on another developer machine (both windows), the reverse order is the working order!!

```
var portalTemplates = gulp.src(input)
    .pipe(templateCache('portal', { module: 'common.templates', standalone: true, root: templatePathPrefix + '/' + portalName + '/angular' }));

var sharedTemplates = gulp.src(sharedFiles.templates)
    .pipe(templateCache('shared', { module: 'common.templates', root: templatePathPrefix + '/_shared/angular' }));

gulpMerge(sharedTemplates, portalTemplates)
    .pipe(gulpTap(function (f) {
        console.log(f.path, ' => ', f.contents.length);
    }))
    .pipe(concat('merged'))
    .pipe(gulpTap(function (f) {
        console.log(f.path, ' => ', f.contents.length);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output.folder));
```

to illustrate the issue, I've added those `console.log`s before and after concat.

On this order I get

```
shared => <length>
```

on reverse order (i.e. `gulpMerge(portalTemplates, sharedTemplates)`)

```
portal => <length>
shared => <length>
merged => <length>
```

Any help is very much appreciated!